# jQuery unobtrusive validation on dynamically generated radio buttons in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I've got a dynamic forms app and am trying to apply proper unobtrusive validation for the form elements and am having trouble with getting the form to display validation errors the way I want.

My partial view to render the radio button form items looks like this:

```
@model FormItem

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-item">@Model.Text</div>
<div class="form-item-responses">
    @foreach(FormItemResponse formItemResponse in Model.Responses.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder))
    {
        if(Model.Required)
        {
            @Html.RadioButton(Model.Id.ToString(), formItemResponse.Id, formItemResponse.DefaultSelection, new { @class = "required", data_val = "true", data_val_required = "*"}) @formItemResponse.Text

        }
        else
        {
             @Html.RadioButton(Model.Id.ToString(), formItemResponse.Id, formItemResponse.DefaultSelection) @formItemResponse.Text
        }

        <text>&nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
    }
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="@Model.Id.ToString()" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the final markup for those not familiar with MVC:

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-item">Form Item Text Here</div>
<div class="form-item-responses">
    <input class="required" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" name="026d44a7-fa55-4fe8-8d2f-4f561c77c716" type="radio" value="dcfa4a9a-53e1-44d5-b6b3-a133673bfa2e" />Yes            &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input class="required" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" name="026d44a7-fa55-4fe8-8d2f-4f561c77c716" type="radio" value="0042876b-2362-4f65-9c8a-dddf7f8206e8" />No            &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input class="required" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" name="026d44a7-fa55-4fe8-8d2f-4f561c77c716" type="radio" value="a0918eab-93b6-4e45-a78d-301e28571037" />NA            &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="026d44a7-fa55-4fe8-8d2f-4f561c77c716" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

In works in that any group of radio buttons get properly validated, and the `*` comes up next to the item. However, what I would like to do is change the text color of everything in `.form-item-responses` to red. Not just the validation error message.

How can I do this? I tried using the `invalidHandler` like so:

```
 $("#items-form").validate({
      invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
          var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
          console.log(errors);
          $("input.input-validation-error").each(function() {
              this.parent().css("color", "red");
          });
      }
  });
```

But that appears to override the default behavior and just put a black `This field is required` next to the first radio button in each answer group. I want the default behavior and then just this extra change.

Comment: Any javascript issue firing in Console for your browser?

Comment: None that I see no. I even put the console log for the error count in there to make sure it was getting to that function, and it is. But that is all that happens then.

Comment: have input tags been set (in runtime) with the class ".input-validation-error" after validation?

Comment: @JuniorMayhé I am not sure about the default behavior of the validate plugin, but I believe that happens during validation.

Comment: I just add the appropriate class "required", include the appropriate scripts, and when submitting, if something isn't filled in that is required, it then adds the input-validation-error class to that radio group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed this was getting the validator from the form as a variable, then accessing the settings in document.ready like so:

```
        var validatorData = $('#items-form').data('validator');
        validatorData.settings.highlight = function (element, errorClass) {
            $(element).parent().parent().css("color", "red");
        };
```

I am not sure why the first way I tried it didn't work. As that seems to be the way in the documentation and on many examples online.